# Google script google sheet to calendar TypeError: Cannot find function createEvent in object Calendar. (line 18, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have attempted to create a google script that will create calendar events based on information within cells in google sheets. I have gotten to the point where everything is labeled and marked, but an error is occuring that states:

> TypeError: Cannot find function createEvent in object Calendar. (line 18, file "Code")

Here is the code I have written:

```
function calInsert() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 25;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 9);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName( "EC Calendar" );
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var title = row[1];  // First column
    var tstart = row[2]; // Second column
    var tstop = row[3];
    var desc = row[4];       
    var loc = row[5];
    var cmmail = row[6];
    var leamail = row[7];

  var event = cal.createEvent(title, new Date(tstart), new Date(tstop), {description:desc,location:loc,guests:cmmail,guests:leamail});
```

}
}

Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarsByName%28String%29) the return value of `CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName` should be array of _Calendars_, not single _Calendar_ object. But in your error message it seems to be of type _Calendar_ already. Have you tried to use `cal[0].createEvent(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("EC Calendar"); 
This gives you an array of calendars with that name. Change this to:

var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("EC Calendar")[0]; //Gets the correct calendar
This gives you the first Calendar with the name. I tried the below code:

```
function calInsert() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
 var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5);
 var data = dataRange.getValues();
 var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName( "calendar ID" )[0];
 for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var title = row[0];  // First column
    var tstart = row[2]; // Second column
    var tstop = row[3];
    Logger.log(tstop);
    var desc = row[1];       
    var loc = row[4];
   //var cmmail = row[6];
   //var leamail = row[7];

   cal.createEvent(title, new Date(tstart), new Date(tstop),     {description:desc,location:loc}); 
}
}
```

I am able to create event in my calendar. If needed, you can send cmmail and leamail to createEvent.

Comment: THANK YOU! I got it to run after adding your suggestions and adjusting the row #s and it populated the calendar with the correct inputs... I just have 2 additional questions: 1. how would I tell it to add 2guest emails (cmmail and leamail) and send invite email (if possible), and 2. Is it possible make it so that if the function is run multiple times, it will NOT create duplicate events?

Comment: @T Raser, Please accept my answer if it helped you to resolve your problem